# Can we write was and were in the form of contraction?

Tags: past-tense, contractions

Can we write for example "We were waiting for you" in this way "We're waiting for you"? and if we can how to differentiate between the past and present in these sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`We're`, `they're` and `you're` are only used in the present tense, as are `she's`, `he's` and `it's`, I'm sure.

As @ColinFine states, `she's`, `he's` and `it's` can also mean `she has`, `he has` and `it has`, so it depends on context.

Comment: While you're right, I'd point out that _she's_  etc can also stand for _she has_, and so can be perfect: _She's seen him_. But it can't stand for _she was_.